# Jupyter notebook os.path.isfile returns false when the file exists

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently running a program in Jupyter Notebook but when I provide a path it says that it can't find the folder. I used os.path.isfile('/Users/name/Desktop/..etc') to check the path, but it says false. What went wrong?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What happens when you run ls on the particular file name from a terminal?

Comment: `"...it says that it can't find the folder."` It will return `False` for a folder. A folder is not a file. That's why we have [os.path.isdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir).

Comment: can you use shell `ls filepath` to check you entered path is correct

Comment: Thanks guys! I used os.path.isdir() and it worked!